# How do I know if I've been hacked?

Tags: ipad

I opened an email that appeared to come from PayPal, and it took me to a website.
When it loaded I got warning that popped up on my screen saying that I'm being phished and/or hacked and I need to call Apple ASAP. Since I've opened the email my tablet is acting weird.

What should I do? Could I have been hacked?

Comment: Welcome to ask Different! Please add more details to your question; Did you enter personal information on the –possibly fake– PayPal site? Like your user and password? What do you mean when you say your tablet is acting weird? Thanks!

Comment: It's unlikely that your iPad got infected solely by browsing in Safari. In what way is it *acting weird*?

Comment: If you want to edit this to include a picture of the pop up message, we could possibly help narrow things down. I've added a generic "this is phishing" answer but without details this is quite broad to know how to answer and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Often this is just a ruse to get you to call the number and then pay a fee or provide a credit card number.  In this case you weren't really hacked and damage is not done unless you make the phone call.

Not sure what you mean by the tablet acting "weird" so its difficult to answer your question with any precision.  Assuming you are concerned about the behavior of your tablet after opening the email, the best thing is to erase your tablet and reset to a back-up prior to the email.

Assuming you released personal information to the fake PayPal site, you should change your password and inform Paypal ASAP (they may need you to get a new account).  If you use the same username/password for other financial sites, then you need to change your password and contact those financial institutions as well.

Comment: Resetting will not solve the phishing problem if the OP fell for it.

Comment: Yes, as we both noted we need more information.  The post implied a greater concern for how the tablet was behaving as opposed to identify theft issues.  But assuming the OP gave out her personal info I suppose she needs to change her password ASAP, inform paypal and cancel other credit/debit/bank accounts if the same username/password is used for other sites.

Comment: Exactly, would you please add that info to your answer, to cover that base?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has many support resources to ensure you are educated and secure:

## Phishing & Other Suspicious Emails

http://www.apple.com/legal/more-resources/phishing/

I would read through that and perhaps report the mails you received if you feel it's a targeted attack at you or Apple's customers. Since you have a PayPal attempt, you could see if they have a similar resource but let's steer the conversation to Apple Products since we're Ask Different and not Ask Paypal :-)